# How to change the Bing Map trial key to enterprise Key in wp7 app?

Tags: bing-maps, enterprise

I am using the bing map in one of my apps.The Bing map key I am using  is trial key and Now I want to change this key to Enterprise.

How to Change the same key(trial key) to Enterprise key.How much I have to paid to change this trial key to Enterprise key and What are the steps to do the same.

Answer (score 0):

first you will need to turn your Bing Maps account into an Enterprise account. To do this contact maplic@microsoft.com

Once this is done you can then go into the Bing Maps portal and create an Enterprise Bing Maps key and then update your app with this new key.

The cost for an Enterprise key would depend on the number of transactions being generated by your app and the type of app it is.

If it is a publicly available app and generates less than 50,000 transactions a day then create a basic key instead as this would fall under the free terms of use.